# Make a div be in a lower position than in the class

Tags: html, css

So, i need to make a div to be in a lower position, for example

```
.example {
  top: 10px;
}
```

and my Html:

```
<div class="example" style="top: (...)+10">(...)</div>
```

This doesn't work, obviously. But in the end i need to have

```
top: 20px;
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: The element has to be positioned for `top` to work. E.g. `position:relative`. And you can look into the [CSS `calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) if you need to calculate the sum of several values

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to do it with a php code between your htlm codes.
You can write the same code in your project:

`<?php $inc = 10;
echo '<div class="example" style="top: '. $inc . '+10"> Text goes here </div>';
?>`

Or if there is requirement to detect front-end & browser configuration, you can do it simply same on `jQuery` or `Javascript`